# How to Share the web page content (not the link to page) with javascript/phonegap on android phones

Tags: javascript, cordova

Dear StackOverflow community,

We have an app that is written with Web technologies as javascript, css, html5, jquery. And We are using phonegap/cordova to make our app hybrid.

The issue we have:

There is a questionnaire (part of our app), users fill out some questions, and the result is shown on a page.

What we need is to share this page (it is content) via email (or maybe print it to pdf).

There is a cordova plugin html2pdf that works with cordova 3.3

But our project uses cordova 2.3.

NOTE: We tried jsPDF to print page content to PDF, it works fine on desktop browsers, but not on android phones.

Any ideas how to do this using javascript/phonegap/cordova on android phones?

Best,

Comment: you can try the screenshot plugin

Comment: is it phonegap/cordova plugin?

Comment: yes, one of them https://github.com/gitawego/cordova-screenshot